# iOS Charts not showing all xAxis Value

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am writing an **iOS App** in **Swift 4.2**
I am using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library to display **Horizontal Bar Chart**. I need to set its xAxis Values. Only last value is being displayed.

**Issue Screenshot:**
[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```
@IBOutlet var chartView: HorizontalBarChartView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        xAxis.granularity = 1
        xAxis.enabled=true

    xAxis.setLabelCount(3, force: false) //Not working as per expectations
   xAxis.valueFormatter=IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["A","B","C"])  //Not working as per expectations




        self.setDataCount(3,values:[142000,122400,100110])
        chartView.animate(yAxisDuration: 2.5)
    }


    func setDataCount(_ count: Int, values:[Double]) {
        let barWidth = 2.0
        let spaceForBar = 4.0
        var n=0
        let yVals = (0..<count).map { (i) -> BarChartDataEntry in

            let val = values[n]
            n+=1

            return BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i)*spaceForBar, y: val)

        }

        let set1 = BarChartDataSet(entries: yVals, label: "DataSet")
        set1.drawIconsEnabled = false

        let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set1)
        data.setValueFont(UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Light", size:10)!)
        data.barWidth = barWidth

        chartView.data = data

        //let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
        //xAxis.setLabelCount(3, force: false)
        //xAxis.valueFormatter=IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["A","B","C"])
    }
```

I tried to find solutions:

```
xAxis.valueFormatter=IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["A","B","C"])
```

but these are not working.

Comment: what solution you tried? is this resolved?

Comment: use setLabelCount

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the default functionality of `IndexAxisValueFormatter`

You have to code your own custom `IAxisValueFormatter` like this

```
final class CustomFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {

    var labels: [String] = []

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

        let count = self.labels.count

        guard let axis = axis, count > 0 else {
            return ""
        }

        let factor = axis.axisMaximum / Double(count)

        let index = Int((value / factor).rounded())

        if index >= 0 && index < count {
            return self.labels[index]
        }

        return ""
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```
 let customFormater = CustomFormater()
 customFormater.labels = ["A","B","C"]

 chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = customFormater
```

Make sure the size/count of the data and labels is the same or it wont give you the desired results.

Comment: Middle value is appearing repeated.  Its coming like ["A","B","B","C"]

Comment: @AtifShabeer As i said `Make sure the size/count of the data and labels is the same or it wont give you the desired results.`

Comment: If i use chartView?.xAxis.setLabelCount(3, force: false) it shows 2 values, I need to write chartView?.xAxis.setLabelCount(4, force: false) . Why an extra?

Comment: Also, another issue, titles are being printed in reverse C,B,A instead of A,B,C

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora. YES USE setLabelCount

Comment: @AtifShabeer actually my labels are not numeric i mean i am having months as x axis and expenditure as y axis so it is not showing last label of x axis

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora I think this issue is fixed in latest version of charts

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora Also you can try toggling property: avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled

Comment: @AtifShabeer I am using latest only

Comment: @RaziTiwana I am using above solution but        
 ` let factor = axis.axisMaximum / Double(count)`
this calculation is skipping one index

Comment: @RaziTiwana any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I updated your given code please check changes.

I hope its work for you.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var chartView: HorizontalBarChartView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
    xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    xAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    xAxis.granularity = 1
    xAxis.enabled=true

    xAxis.setLabelCount(3, force: false) //Not working as per expectations
    xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["A","B","C"])//AxisValueFormatter(values: ["A","B","C"])  //Not working as per expectations

    self.setDataCount(3,values:[142000,122400,100110])
    chartView.animate(yAxisDuration: 2.5)
}


func setDataCount(_ count: Int, values:[Double]) {

    let yVals = (0..<count).map { (i) -> BarChartDataEntry in

        let val = values[i]

        return BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val)
    }

    let set1 = BarChartDataSet(values: yVals, label: "DataSet")
    set1.drawIconsEnabled = false

    let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set1)

    data.setValueFont(UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Light", size:10)!)
    //data.barWidth = barWidth

    chartView.data = data

    //let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
    //xAxis.setLabelCount(3, force: false)
    //xAxis.valueFormatter=IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["A","B","C"])
}
```

}

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: When you add x value for chart entry then  IndexAxisValueFormatter consider this value as index 

So if you want to display  xAxis then you have to add x value as index like 0,1,2

Comment: let yVals = (0..<count).map { (i) -> BarChartDataEntry in

        let val = values[i]

        return BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val)
    }

//data.barWidth = barWidth

Comment: Ok. Now can you kindly tell me how to display those values (Y values) after bar?

Comment: Ok. Now can you kindly tell me how to display those values (Y values) after bar? Because above screenshot is Swift 5, in which you can also see the values but my code is Swift 4.2 in which bar values are not visible